# R Loop not Looping the Correct Number of Times

Tags: r

My DF contains 9 columns, 3 sets of 3. In the total row I'm attempting to make, I sum the first column, sum the second column and divide in the third column. Repeat for the second set and repeat for the third set. Except my loop is not working. It is calculating the number of sets correctly, 3, but is only looping twice. My results totals for the first 6 columns/first 2 sets.

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(200,200,200),b=c(20,20,20),c=c(10,10,10),d=c(100,100,100),e=c(2,2,2),f=c(50,50,50),g=c(200,200,200),h=c(20,20,20),i=c(10,10,10))

i <- 1
totals <- vector()

for (sets in (range(1:length(df))/3)){
  x <- colSums(df[i:i], na.rm = TRUE)
  i <- i + 1
  y <- colSums(df[i:i], na.rm = TRUE)
  i <- i + 1
  z <- x/y
  i <- i + 1
  totals <- c(totals,x,y,z)
}

totals <- c(0,totals)
print(totals)
```

Comment: What values do you want `sets` to take? `1:length(df)` is `1, 2, 3, ..., 8, 9`. `range(1:length(df))` is `1, 9`, because `range()` returns the min and max. Then you divide by 3, so you get `.3333, 3`. So you are asking R for 2 iterations, one with `sets = 0.3333` and one with `sets = 1`. Perhaps you want to remove the `range()` to keep all the values?

Comment: Then, surprisingly, you don't use `sets` inside the loop at all, instead keeping separate track of an `i` variable... not sure what's going on with that. You are looping over `sets` so you almost certainly should use `sets` inside the loop.

Comment: Lastly, you use `df[i:i]` a couple times in the loop. The sequence from `i` to `i` will just be `i`... so this is equivalent to `df[i]`

Comment: It would help a lot if you could post the expected results for your sample input. Do you want `(sum(df$a) + sum(df$b)) / sum(df$c)`, and similarly for column groups `d, e, f` and `g, h, i`?

Comment: To answer some of the questions: I am trying to loop through sets of columns. A column set consists of 3 columns. the first col of a set I want to sum, the second col of the set I want to sum, and the third col of the set I want to divide. the table will always come with columns 1,2,3 beloging to eachother. 4,5,6 belonging to eachother, and 7,8,9 belonging to each other. the variable i is there for me to know what col I am currently on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments your undertaking looks not very logical in terms of how things should be done... anyhow, if I understood your problem correctly a possible solutions would be this:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(200,200,200),b=c(20,20,20),c=c(10,10,10),d=c(100,100,100),e=c(2,2,2),f=c(50,50,50),g=c(200,200,200),h=c(20,20,20),i=c(10,10,10))


i <- 1
totals <- vector()

for (sets in 1:nrow(df)){
   x <- colSums(df[i:i], na.rm = TRUE)
   i <- i + 1
   y <- colSums(df[i:i], na.rm = TRUE)
   i <- i + 1
   z <- x/y
   i <- i + 1
   totals <- c(totals,x,y,z)
}

totals <- c(0,totals)
print(totals)
```